# Change Bootstrap grid and container width from 1170px to 1000px for desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, responsive-design, less

Anyone know how I can change the grid container in bootstrap from the standard 1170px to a 1000px with 12 columns. I have been trying to change the column width and gutter width in variables.less but haven't been able to change anything.

Many thanks

Patrick

Was trying this:

```
// 1200px min
```

@gridColumnWidth1200:     65px;

@gridGutterWidth1200:     20px;

@gridRowWidth1200:        (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth1200) + (@gridGutterWidth1200 * (@gridColumns - 1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about bootstrap 2.3.2, not version 3.  If so, in variables.less you have the following code:

```
// GRID
// --------------------------------------------------


// Default 940px grid
// -------------------------
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         60px;
@gridGutterWidth:         20px;
@gridRowWidth:            (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@gridColumns - 1));

// 1200px min
@gridColumnWidth1200:     70px;
@gridGutterWidth1200:     30px;
@gridRowWidth1200:        (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth1200) + (@gridGutterWidth1200 * (@gridColumns - 1));

// 768px-979px
@gridColumnWidth768:      42px;
@gridGutterWidth768:      20px;
@gridRowWidth768:         (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth768) + (@gridGutterWidth768 * (@gridColumns - 1));
```

which points you to all the variables and math involved...  make the appropriate changes to the variables to make it add up to the new size you are looking for.  Maybe you were making changes to gridColumnWidth instead of gridColumnWidth1200

Comment: Thanks Erikruni was trying to modify the gridColumnWidth1200: and gridGutterWidth1200: but still doesnt have any effect. Maybe the container that is set 1170 is effecting the change

Comment: the container most definately is what you need to change, but that change should have done it.  The container width is created from the gridColumnWidth and gridGutterWidth variables.  Are you sure after changing your less files you are regenerating the css properly?

Comment: Awhh yes the problem was that I was including the css/bootstrap-responsive.css file in the html and was not adding the responsive.less file to the bootstrap.less file. Thanks a million Erik :)